# Need help reading words between <> and saving to array

Tags: java, file, io, split

Hello all I am trying to take a predetermined .txt file as shown below and read only the words between the < >, then add them to an array and write them to an HTML file.
the txt file is as follows.
for some reason its not showing the words in-between the < > on here.

```
"" = word between < > 

A, <""">
B, <""">
C, <""">
etc.
```

here is my current code for attempting to read from the file, I understand the .split and .delimeter problem is these methods read everything before the chosen character.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TickTacTwice {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Muhammed/Documents/tic_tac_twice.txt"));

    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {

        String S = sc.nextLine();

        String [] words = S.split("<");


        System.out.println(words[0]);
    }


    sc.close();
}

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: edit your post and put that code into it, formatted using the code button.

Comment: Please edit the original question and add your code using the appropriate code tags.

Comment: Yes sorry about that I am new and was having a little trouble with it, but i have gotten it thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are just printing the first item in the split array "words", is it possible the first occurrence of a <> is empty? To view all items in the array you can use a loop like the following:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Each of those lines will contain all characters until the next "<" so you will then need to trim to the ">"

An easier way to do this is using Regular Expressions - there are some good examples here on StackOverflow.

Edit: Combining your code with TAsks would produce what you are after:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TickTacTwice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Muhammed/Documents/tic_tac_twice.txt"));

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String S = sc.nextLine();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>");

            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(S);

            while(m.find()) {

                 System.out.println(m.group(0));
            }
        }

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I realize that but i am trying just to read whats in-between the < > i don't want to include the < > into the array to be written into my .html file. I will do some research on using regular expressions. Thanks